# Equality case of the log-Bogomolov-Miyaoka-Yau inequality

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-surfaces

The Bogomolov-Miyaoka-Yau inequality for sufaces says that if $X$ is a smooth projective minimal surface of general type then $c_1(X)^2 \le 3 c_2(X)$. It is a theorem of Yau (I think) that equality holds if and only if $X$ is uniformized by the unit ball in $\mathbb{C}^2$.

There is also a version of the inequality for log pairs $(X, D)$ where $X$ is smooth projective surface and $D$ is an snc divisor on $X$. Then the inquality states that,

$$ (K_X + D)^2 \le 3 c_2(\Omega_X(\log{D})) $$
if $K_X + D$ is an effective $\mathbb{Q}$-divisor. Is anything known about which varieties can achieve the equality case?

Comment: I believe the analogous statement is true and proved by R. Kobayashi *Einstein-Kahler V-metrics on open Stake  V-surfaces..." Math Ann 1985, but you should check. I don't have time to right now.

Comment: Indeed the equality occurs exactly for ball quotients. [This paper](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwi1puy2yKyEAxVFTqQEHVO_ASgQFnoECBIQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fprojecteuclid.org%2Fjournals%2Fproceedings-of-the-japan-academy-series-a-mathematical-sciences%2Fvolume-65%2Fissue-7%2FA-numerical-characterization-of-ball-quotients-for-normal-surfaces-with%2F10.3792%2Fpjaa.65.238.pdf&usg=AOvVaw3r1MKdnXYV--VjYb3qfS0u&opi=89978449) by Kobayashi-Nakamura-Sakai contains a statement with very general hypotheses.